# Azure SQL database very slow for some queries

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

I am connecting to a SQL database in Azure. Paging through the data works fine.

There are millions of records in the database, and data is constantly being added as the database is connected to a "firehose" api.

Some queries work without issue, while others just end up timing out...

The `id` column is indexed, but it is not a primary key, nor is it unique. I have no control over the database.

As an example of a query which does not return:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tableA WHERE id='QFA6007-1496148480-adhoc-0' ORDER BY time DESC;
```

Simply changing the `id` may make the query work (but also may not...).
The id's for the queries not working, are most definitely in the database...

I've tried modifying the WHERE clause to include more constraints, but it does not seem to make a difference.

Is there something wrong with my query? Is there away to increase performance?

Comment: A composite clustered index on both `id` and `time` would be best for performance of this particular query. Have you reviewed the execution plan or checked for blocking?

Comment: @DanGuzman Nope, not done that. Can I do it without having write access to the DB? I am not in control of the DB and only have read access.

Comment: Your DBA would need to change the index.  You'll need to compare the execution plans of the good and bad queries to see how much the index change might help. If both have the same plan, the root cause might be blocking.

Comment: Wait....you have an ETL database on the same instance you have your read queries? For one thing, your poor statistics are taking a beating and another what are the details of this query? Huge I/Os? Significant memory usage? Returning too many rows or huge memory grants (such as cost from an ORDER BY)?